# AWS Glue Insert and update into oracle table

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

we are trying to migrate few jobs from informatica to aws glue
most of the logic and transformation have been completed.
The final step is to insert the data back into a oracle db(not present in aws rds) which is in public.
Is it possible to perform the insert and update in aws glue ?

I tried using using cx_Oracle module but it's erroring out

Answer (score 0):

Even though, you can use a Glue pyspark job or a Glue python-shell job for this, Pyspark is not meant to do UPDATE/INSERT operations row by row - You can append(INSERT) or you can replace the entire table.

[if you were to do it using a Python-shell job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html) (Python V3.9 or above), you need to

- download the JDBC Oracle driver and add it under "Dependent jars path" in the console. The full S3 URI should be added eg. `s3://bucket-name/jars/oracle-jdbc.jar`
- Next, add the additional package needed. In the console, it is under "Python library path". `--additional-python-modules cx-Oracle==8.3.0` You can download the correct version of whl file from Pypi.org
- If you are in a restricted network that restricts the Glue job from downloading the python package to install (you will see the below error, when adding additional packages), add the whl file for cx_Oracle into S3 and add those eg. `--additional-python-modules s3://bucket-name/whls/cx-oracle--py3-none-any.whl`. Find the correct  whl file from https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files - choose for python 3.9, manylinux, x86_64

> Download error on https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle : [Errno 99] Cannot
> assign requested address -- Some packages may not be found! Couldn't
> find index page for 'cx_Oracle' (maybe misspelled?)

Test that your job can now import the modules.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Thanks Ananth for the reply 
i tried using the cx_oracle it was erroring out with
((DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"))

The catch is, this environment variable must be set even before the python script starts execution. So we were thinking to host the oracle client on an S3 bucket and download it to a location within the python script which is added to the AWS Glue Python Shell, it didnt work.

However in lambda it works because it lets us configure the variables

Comment: You are right - I realize, it looks for ENV variables ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/19.19/client64 and ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib .
Use python-oracledb instead of cx_Oracle. python-oracledb by default runs in a "Thin mode" that doesn't need Oracle Client libraries so you won't get DPI-1047

also found this answer that suggests the same - https://repost.aws/articles/ARn9PYzINASuerh29geCWd_Q/aws-glue-python-shell-oracle-db-connection-solution

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help it helped me a lot
will use the above link to set this up